# Angular Reactive Form Validation : Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a Reactive Form with a custom `FormControl`. The first time the screen is loaded, although the custom control is a required field, my Form is valid.

If I trigger any change, for instance by ticking a checkbox in my form, then the form is marked has invalid until I fill a value to my custom control.

If I reset the value of my custom control, then the form is marked as invalid again and it just works as expected from then on.

So the problem occurs ONLY when the form is loaded the first time on screen.

I've noticed the following exception in the console:

[image]

This error is triggered by the validator of my custom control because if I comment it, the error goes away.

Below is the code of my custom control. Am I doing something wrong ?

```
import { Component, forwardRef, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, FormControl, NG_VALIDATORS, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-multiple-checkbox',
  templateUrl: './multiple-checkbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./multiple-checkbox.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => MultipleCheckboxComponent),
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => MultipleCheckboxComponent),
      multi: true
    }]
})
export class MultipleCheckboxComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

  value = [];
  disabled = false;

  @Input() public options: { key, value }[];

  onTouched: any;
  onChange: any;


  constructor() { }

  validate({ value }: FormControl) {
   
    const isNotValid = this.value.length === 0;
    return isNotValid && {
      invalid: true
    };
  }

  ngOnInit(): void { }

  evaluate(event, key): void {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.value.push(key);
    } else {
      this.value.splice(this.value.findIndex(i => key === i), 1);
    }

    this.onChange(this.value);
    this.onTouched();
  }

  isChecked(key): boolean {
    return this.value.findIndex(e => e === key) > -1;
  }

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    this.value = value;
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }

}
```

**[EDIT]**
Adding how the custom control is added to the screen in its parent form:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
 <div *ngIf="control.visible">

    <div [ngSwitch]="control.controlType">

        <div *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'">
            <label [attr.for]="control.key">{{control.label}}</label>

            <input [formControlName]="control.key" [id]="control.key" type="checkbox"
                (change)="evaluate(control.key)">
        </div>

<!--  THIS IS MY CUSTOM CONTROL -->

        <app-multiple-checkbox *ngSwitchCase="'multipleCheckbox'" [formControlName]="control.key"
            [options]="control.options" (change)="evaluate(control.key)">
        </app-multiple-checkbox>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[EDIT]**

Following comment below, the error is triggered by this line in my form :

```
<button type="submit" color="accent" (click)="save()" 
 [disabled]="catalogForm.invalid">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: Could you show how you are using this custom component, e.g. how you embed it in your template? And how does the `validate` method get called? Do you use it as `ValidatorFn` of the `FormControl` where this component is used?

Comment: @Eddi I edited my question with missing info. I just implemented the  `Validator` interface, so no need to do any other calls. Again, works just fine except the first time (before the form becomes dirty)

Comment: @Sam This does look fine to me. The error message you provided says something about the `[disabled]` attribute in `catalog.component.html` on line 11. So basically whatever expression you used there changed "too soon". In most cases I know of this occurs when you change the value of the expression within `ngAfterViewInit`.

Comment: actually with reactive forms more common way is to subscribe to `valueChanges` of the form in ts file instead of template `(change)` handlers. I believe it can fix your issue

Comment: @Eddi, yes, the error is triggered by the submit button `disabled` attribute. I'ved edited my question. Removing this attribute removes the error, but of course I don't want to do that and this does not solve the original problem which is the valid form that should be invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Expression has changed after it was checked

The above error appears only in development mode.
In production this error is not there.

To remove this error in development mode

```js
import ChangeDetectorRef from  @angular/core

constructor(private changeDecRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

then

````
    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.value.push(key);
    } else {
      this.value.splice(this.value.findIndex(i => key === i), 1);
    }

    this.onChange(this.value);
    this.onTouched();

    /// ADD THIS FUNCTION ///
    this.changeDecRef.detectChanges();
  }```
````

Comment: But I can't help thinking that this is related to the validation issue that I'm facing though. That wouldn't explain why the form is valid when it should not be.

Comment: it shows that in production mode something can go wrong. so you can't just ignore it

Comment: If I add your code, the error is still there and my problem remains.

Comment: @sam you have to add that in catalouge.component.ts file..

Comment: I tried that too, but then nothing works anymore. The FormControls are no longer added to the Form.

Comment: Actually when Angular load first time...it runs it's change detection functionality to check the variable biding..after that if any variable which is bound with HTML would be changed then angular cannot detect that..you have to forcefully detect that changes by
this.changeDecRef.detectChanges();
This error does not persist in production server

Comment: @sam can you show me your catalog.component.ts code?